# Background image not working in Safari 4 /5

Tags: css, html, safari, less

I have a logo image that is refusing to display in Safari 4/5. Can anyone shed any light on this?

This is the CSS / (uncompiled less) -

```
background: url("../img/logos%20and%20icons/logoLrg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / contain rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
@media(max-width:400px){
    background: url("../img/logos%20and%20icons/logoSML.png") no-repeat scroll 0 right / contain rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
display: block;
height: 50px;
margin-top: 29px;
width: 205px;
z-index: 255;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try without spaces

```
background: url("../img/logos and icons/logoLrg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / contain rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
@media(max-width:400px){
    background: url("../img/logos and icons/logoSML.png") no-repeat scroll 0 right / contain rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
display: block;
height: 50px;
margin-top: 29px;
width: 205px;
z-index: 255;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use url encoding to set a path for a background image in a style sheet. It seems to me that if you replace `%20` by a `+` sign you probably solve that issue. I'll come back with more information about it though.